# In emacs, what is the difference between cl-flet and cl-letf?

Tags: emacs

I understand that both are used to temporarily change the value of a function. Beyond the fact that `cl-flet` is a function and `cl-letf` is a macro, when do you use them?

Comment: What does `C-h f` tell you? What do nodes **Function Bindings** and **Modify Macros** of the **CL** manual (`C-h i m cl`) tell you?

Comment: Of course I've checked the manual. I've read all I could find about these functions. I'm afraid I cannot understand what the documentation is saying. For instance, for `cl-flet`: "Make temporary function bindings. The bindings can be recursive and the scoping is lexical, but capturing them
in closures will only work if `lexical-binding' is in use." Wut?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a bit more reading (e.g., in this case, about lexical binding, if you are not familiar with that). But if you find something that you think is wrong or missing from the doc, please consider reporting it so it can be improved: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Perhaps the use of `cl-flet` and seemingly similar functions should be elaborated upon in the doc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary to be an intermediate to advanced Emacs user/programmer to understand certain aspects of Emacs and advanced users/programmers will not always take the time to explain it to beginners.  Try to look for specific examples using Google for each function that demonstrate how to use them, and ask for clarification as to either one of them individually, instead of asking for a compare and contrast.  If you search hard enough, you will likely find a few examples of each that will give you a better picture of how the functions are used.

Comment: @UndeadKernel: The doc you cite seems wrong: `cl-flet` bindings *cannot* be recursive.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The bindings can be recursive

If the function definition *calls itself by name*, which function will be called? (compare `cl-flet` vs `cl-labels` behaviour).

> Scoping is lexical ... capturing them in closures ...

Read about lexical binding/scope vs dynamic binding/scope.

`cl-letf` can be used to set *dynamically-bound* function values, by using a PLACE of `(symbol-function 'FUNC)` for some FUNC. This is analogous to the deprecated `flet`.

Any supported PLACE can be specified, though -- `cl-letf` isn't *only* for function bindings.

> when do you use them?

When you want to temporarily define (or override) a function. The scoping rules you require for any given use-case will determine which option you would use.

---

- `(cl-flet ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)`

  FUNC is visible only to the code in FORM.
- `(cl-labels ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)`

  FUNC is visible both to the code in FORM and also to the code in FUNC's own BODY.
- `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'FUNC) VALUE) ...) BODY...)`

  FUNC is visible to absolutely everything until BODY has finished being evaluated.

---

Some (fairly contrived) examples...

In the first example, the temporary function we have defined is *recursive* -- it *calls itself* -- and therefore we use `cl-labels`:

(n.b. this isn't a robust factorial implementation; it's just for demonstration purposes.)

```el
(defun my-factorial (number)
  "Show the factorial of the argument."
  (interactive "nFactorial of: ")
  (cl-labels ((factorial (n) (if (eq n 1)
                                 1
                               (* n (factorial (1- n))))))
    (message "Factorial of %d is %d" number (factorial number))))
```

If you change `cl-labels` to `cl-flet` you will get an error as soon as the inner `(factorial (1- n))` is evaluated, because *within* our temporary function, no function `factorial` is known.

If you were to then define a global `factorial` function which unconditionally returns the value `1`:

```el
(defun factorial (n) 1)
```

Then the `factorial` function defined by `cl-flet` will see *that* when it calls `factorial`, and `my-factorial` would calculate `(* n 1)` as the value for any argument `n`.

When no recursion is needed, `cl-flet` is fine to use:

```el
(defun my-square (number)
  "Show the square of the argument."
  (interactive "nSquare of: ")
  (cl-flet ((square (n) (* n n)))
    (message "Square of %d is %d" number (square number))))
```

Both `cl-labels` and `cl-flet` provide lexically-scoped functions, visible *only* to the code written within the bodies of those macro calls; and in particular *not* to the code of any other functions which we may be *calling*.

If you are defining a helper function such as in the examples above, lexical scoping is probably what you want, as there's a reasonable chance you'll only be calling your helper within the macro body.

If you are trying to temporarily *override* an existing function, however, there's a pretty fair chance you'll need the functions you're calling to see the override. In such cases you need the override to have dynamic scope.

In the past `flet` was the way to provide dynamic scope for temporary functions, but `flet` is now deprecated in favour of using `cl-letf` with a 'place' of `(symbol-function 'FUNC)`

In the following examples, the multiplication function is overridden, and the dynamic scope means that `my-square` and `my-factorial` will see and use our temporary definition of multiplication.

```el
(defun my-bad-square ()
  "Maths gone wrong."
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function '*) '+))
    (call-interactively 'my-square)))
```

```el
(defun my-bad-factorial ()
  "More maths gone wrong."
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function '*)
             (lambda (x y) (- x y))))
    (call-interactively 'my-factorial)))
```

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation part where PLACE is defined? It is not clear to me, from the documentation of cl-letf, what exactly I can use as a PLACE.

Comment: Start at `C-h i g (elisp) Generalized Variables` and then read the `Setting Generalized Variables` node.

Comment: Tangential note: Overriding `*` in those last examples works only in uncompiled elisp.  In byte-compiled elisp, `*` has its own byte-code, and it cannot be overridden (so you get different results from that code depending on whether or not it's compiled).