# How to call the original function in a cl-letf overridden function?

Tags: emacs

In elisp, `cl-letf` can be used to override a function, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550578/in-emacs-what-is-the-difference-between-cl-flet-and-cl-letf) has details about it.

I'd like to call the original function in the overridden function. How can I accomplish that?

In particular, I'd like to disable ediff's "Do you really want to quit?" message, but still keeping other ediff questions. This is my current solution:

```
(defun my-ediff-disable-quit-question (orig-fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p)
             (lambda (prompt) (if (string-prefix-p "Quit this Ediff session" prompt)
                                   t
                                 (<call-original-y-or-n-p> prompt)))))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'ediff-quit :around #'my-ediff-disable-quit-question)
```

As you can see, I override `y-or-n-p`, and check whether the prompt starts with the quit message. If it does, I return `t`. Otherwise I'd like to call the original `y-or-n-p` function.

Comment: Use Emacs-Lisp *advice*. See the Elisp manual, node [Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Comment: @Drew: I already use advice, I only override `y-or-n-p` in ediff's quit function. Sure, this particular problem could be solved if I advice `y-or-n-p` and check for the prompt. But suppose that ediff just only printed "Quit?". Then I don't want to check for this string, because it will disable all y-or-n questions which asks "Quit?", not just ediff's one. I could also add an advice before the prompt, and then remove it, but it is ugly. This is not the first time I needed to call the original function in the overridden one, so it would be good if I knew how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. The original function value can be queried by `(symbol-function 'y-or-n-p)`, and later can be called with `funcall` like this:

```
(defun my-ediff-disable-quit-question (orig-fun &rest args)
  (cl-letf ((orig-y-or-n-p (symbol-function 'y-or-n-p))
            ((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p)
             (lambda (prompt) (if (string-prefix-p "Quit this Ediff session" prompt)
                                  t
                                (funcall orig-y-or-n-p prompt)))))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'ediff-quit :around #'my-ediff-disable-quit-question)
```