# `let loop` (named let) alternative in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, iteration, let

In Scheme there's a `let loop` construct which is essentially the same as creating a self-recursive lambda in-place (aka 'named let'). For example, a factorial of 6 can be written as:

```lisp
(let fact ([x 6])
  (if (< 1 x)
      (* x (fact (- x 1)))
      x))
```

The question is: is there any alternative in elisp. And if there exists one, does it perform tail recursion optimization where possible?

Comment: Note that your code example doesn't use tail calls so TCO wouldn't be applicable to that particular example anyway.

Comment: @Sandra, oh, indeed ;) I was too inattentive. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `cl-labels`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39564067/324105 for a very similar example to your code (along with some other related facilities).

See also: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(cl)Function Bindings`

> does it perform tail recursion optimization where possible?

No, there is no TCO in Emacs Lisp, other than in the work-in-progress [native-compilation](https://akrl.sdf.org/gccemacs.html) feature (where it is currently disabled by default, so presumably not considered ready for general use; but even if it were, it would be a risk to rely upon it other than for personal use, as it's not safe to assume that other people will *also* be running native-compiled code).

For this reason, arbitrary recursion is generally eschewed by elisp programmers in favour of iterative techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Elisp has a `named-let` special form which gets guaranteed tail call optimization: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#index-named_002dlet

I don't know when it was added though.

Comment: Oh, that's really cool! And they also say there's tail recursion optimization, wow! I believe that would totally solve my problem... if only I remembered what I needed this for xD